# Retrieve error object instead of HTTP 400 on Android

Tags: android, error-handling, graphql, apollo-client

I am using [apollo client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) on Android to use graphql services with an Authorization.

When that auth token has expired, an error displays: `HTTP 400` instead of the actual server error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Invalid token.",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Technically speaking, this should execute `onSuccess` but `hasErrors` instead of the `onFailure`.

```
override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
    //I receive the error here. 
}

override fun onResponse(response: Response<T>) {
    if (!response.hasErrors()) {
        //Success
    } else {
        //I should receive the error here...
    }
}
```

Is this related to a `customType`?

Answer (score 1):

## Preface

The system is doing what it is supposed to. An HTTP 400 *is* an error. Therefore passing it through the error callbacks is entirely within reason.

The best solution would be to *deal with the error*.

Perhaps automatically attempt to get a new access token with your refresh token. If that fails, get the user to login again with single sign on.

## Potential solution

If you absolutely want all HTTP 400 error messages to be directed to your successful path, you can always modify your requests to do so.

I haven't tested the following, but it should do what you want it to do.

The interceptor executes the call. It checks the result code from the call. If that call is 400 then we generate a new response based upon the previous response. That new response is modified to send a successful result code.

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor {
            val response = it.call().execute()

            val updatedResponse = if (response.code() == 400) {
                response.newBuilder()
                        .code(200)
                        .build()
            } else {
                response
            }

            updatedResponse
        }
        ...
        .build()

val apollo = ApolloClient.builder()
        .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
        ...
        .build()
```

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already Executed`. Is because I have another interceptor having the Àuthentication Bearer`.

Comment: You could always put the check inside that interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Apollo is quite similar to Retrofit where both uses **OkHttp** to handle Response. The way Apollo handle HTTP responses follows OkHttp rules and behavior. According to [OkHttp Docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/), the `isSuccess` function which determines the success callback:

> Returns true if the code is in [200..300], which means the request was
>   successfully received, understood, and accepted.

In Apollo, this means as long as the status code is NOT between 200-300 it will **always** enter `onFailure` callback (in your case, you got it because of `HTTP 400`).

The only way to make the code enter `onSuccess` callback is by catching the exception in backend side and send `HTTP 200` along with the error message, instead of `HTTP 400`. My team did this, and it works.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But, is there another way of doing this? What if I have not access to the backend? Maybe with an interceptor or something similar? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Amg91 I'm afraid we cannot use interceptor for that. Interceptor is more suitable for a case where we need to put e.g. API Key in every requests. The only workaround is to catch `ApolloException`, then manually map the `e.message` to an error object or `Response<T>` model (whichever suits your needs).

Comment: @Amg91 Also I believe I've provided you the best answer. Please let me know if there is anything else I can help :)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Retrofit please check below code

```
protected void onApiError(Throwable throwable) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        Timber.e(throwable);
        if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
            Response errorResponse = ((HttpException) throwable).response();
            if (errorResponse != null) {
                ResponseBody errorResponseBody = errorResponse.errorBody();
                if (errorResponseBody != null) {
                    ApiError response = new Gson().fromJson(errorResponseBody.charStream(), ApiError.class);
                    if (response != null) {
                        showToast(TextUtils.isEmpty(response.statusMessage) ? response.description : response.statusMessage);
                    } else {
                        showToast(R.string.something_went_wrong);
                    }
                } else {
                    showToast(R.string.something_went_wrong);
                }
            } else {
                showToast(R.string.something_went_wrong);
            }
        } else {
            showToast(R.string.something_went_wrong);
    }
}
```

### ApiError.java

```
@Parcel
public class ApiError {

    @SerializedName("statusCode")
    public int statusCode;

    @SerializedName("statusMessage")
    public String statusMessage;

    @SerializedName("error")
    public String error;

    @SerializedName("error_description")
    public String description;

    public ApiError() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As said on the question, I am using [graphql](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android). So basically I don't know how could I do that...

Comment: Cannot see how this answers the question.

Comment: @azizbekian Apollo and Retrofit both uses OkHttp request and response classes. on api error case parse error body with my above answer and check.